# Common C++ code for iOS and Android - HelloWorld example?

Tags: android, c++, ios, cross-platform

I have been trying to develop simple "HelloWorld" app for iOS and Android mobile platforms. Which will have common C++ code (say "HelloWorld" string as of now). I have goggled a lot and read many articles/forums about writing common C++ code for both iOS and Android platforms, but did not find simple example which demonstrates using common C++ code and using that common C++ code for developing iOS & Android app.
Can somebody point me towards it ? or Share sample which addresses the above use-case?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: how ? can you give more details ?

Comment: i had worked once with cocos not sure abt xcode but it works..here is example for cocos : http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

Comment: Thanks, just gone through it. It uses ready made cocos-2d templates and shell script to create Android app. I am looking for pure c++ app and using it into iOS and Android.

Comment: using cygwin u can run shell whats problem in it i hv developed sample android project on windows 7, it uses objective C, not sure abt PURE C++